# Amazon S3 not working properly on first upload request but working on second

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I am using Amazon S3 webservice to upload my file.

```
        var req = bucket.putObject(params).on('httpUploadProgress', function (progress) {
            ....some action
        }).send(function (err, data) {
            console.log(err);
            ....some action
        });
```

When I execute the above operation it gives me following error.

```
Error: No credentials to load
at i (https://sdk.amazonaws.com/js/aws-sdk-2.0.0-rc13.min.js:4:1104)
at i.a [as getCredentials] (https://sdk.amazonaws.com/js/aws-sdk-2.0.0-rc13.min.js:4:1645)
at a.u (https://sdk.amazonaws.com/js/aws-sdk-2.0.0-rc13.min.js:4:8229)
at a.h [as callListeners] (https://sdk.amazonaws.com/js/aws-sdk-2.0.0-rc13.min.js:5:84)
at a.l (https://sdk.amazonaws.com/js/aws-sdk-2.0.0-rc13.min.js:4:31779)
at a.v (https://sdk.amazonaws.com/js/aws-sdk-2.0.0-rc13.min.js:4:26057)
at a.n (https://sdk.amazonaws.com/js/aws-sdk-2.0.0-rc13.min.js:4:21730)
at n.i [as runTo] (https://sdk.amazonaws.com/js/aws-sdk-2.0.0-rc13.min.js:5:25078)
at https://sdk.amazonaws.com/js/aws-sdk-2.0.0-rc13.min.js:5:25381
at a.<anonymous> (https://sdk.amazonaws.com/js/aws-sdk-2.0.0-rc13.min.js:4:21952)
```

When I again click on same button which execute the above, this time it works properly. What is the issue here

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would guess that the credentials have not been loaded by the time you make your first request. If you read the [SDK source](https://github.com/aws/aws-sdk-js/blob/fb0f95f43ea958846d932bb4e79934a4a548155f/lib/config.js) for getCredentials that raises this error, you'll see this comment: "If you want to ensure that your credentials are loaded prior to a request, you can use this method directly to provide accurate credential data stored in the object".